# Django passing argument missing ) javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm having a trouble why this keep telling me

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I have a list and I want to retrieve it through passing into javascript. Is there anyone know what's the problem? Please give me some help. This is what it looks like:

`views.py`:

```py
def sample(request):
    getlist = request.POST.getlist('batch[]')
    format = {'list': getlist}
    return render(request,'sample.html', format)
```

`sample.html`:

```html
 {% if list %}
    <button type="button" id="reports_btn" class="btn btn-secondary round btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1"  onClick = "reports('{{list}}')" >sample</button>
 {% endif %}
```

javascript:

```js
function reports (list) {
  console.log(list)
}
```

---

Updated my function `views.py`:

```py
@login_required(login_url='log_permission')
def sap_payroll(request):
    classifications = Person.objects.all().values('classification').distinct()
    category = Person.objects.all().values('category').distinct()
    payroll_batch = Person.objects.all().values('payroll_batch').distinct()
    batch_it = Person.objects.all().values('batch_it').distinct()
    paid = Person.objects.all().values('paid').distinct()
    type_payout = Person.objects.all().values('type_payout').distinct()
    paid_with = Person.objects.all().values('paid_by').distinct()
    province = request.POST.get('province', False)
    municipality = request.POST.get('municipality', False)
    barangay = request.POST.get('barangay', False)
    payout_type = request.POST.get('type_payout', False)
    status = request.POST.get('stats', False)
    dte_from = request.POST.get('dte_from', None)
    dte_to = request.POST.get('dte_to', None)
    getlist = request.POST.getlist('batch[]')
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        shes = ['1','2'] # sample testing
        print("doda")
        print(type_payout)
        if getlist and dte_from and dte_to :
            user_list = Person.objects.filter(date_receive__range=[dte_from, dte_to] , payroll_batch__in = getlist )
            bene = UserFilter(request.POST, queryset=user_list)

        elif getlist:
            user_list = Person.objects.filter(payroll_batch__in = getlist)
            bene = UserFilter(request.POST, queryset=user_list) 

        elif dte_from and dte_to:
            user_list = Person.objects.filter(date_receive__range=[dte_from, dte_to])
            bene = UserFilter(request.POST, queryset=user_list)
        else:
            user_list = Person.objects.all()
            bene = UserFilter(request.POST, queryset=user_list)
        
        countsa = bene.qs.count()
        total_amount =bene.qs.aggregate(Sum('amount')).get("amount__sum")
        citys ="CITY OF"
        formats = {'benefeciaries':bene,'municipal':municipality,'province':province,'barangay':barangay,'total':countsa,'amount':total_amount,'cities':citys,'classification':classifications,'category':category,'payroll_batch':payroll_batch,'batch_it':batch_it,'paid':paid,'type_payout':type_payout,'paid_with':paid_with,'payout_type':payout_type,'shes':shes}
        return render(request, 'payroll.html', formats)
    else:
        lists = ['1','2']  #samplee testing
        user_list = Person.objects.all()
        bene = UserFilter(request.GET, queryset=user_list)
        countsa = bene.qs.count()
        formats = {'benefeciaries':bene,'classification':classifications,'category':category,'payroll_batch':payroll_batch,'batch_it':batch_it,'paid':paid,'type_payout':type_payout,'paid_with':paid_with,'payout_type':payout_type,'shes':shes}
        return render (request,'payroll.html',formats)
```

`payroll.html` *(Can't post all since it's too long)*:

```html
{% if municipal or province or barangay or payout_type or shes %}
<button type="button" id="reports_btn" class="btn btn-secondary round btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1"  onClick = "reportss('{{municipal}}','{{province}}','{{barangay}}','{{payout_type}}','{{shes|safe}}')" >Reports</button>
<button type="button" id="remarks_v2" class="btn btn-secondary round btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1"   >Amount/Remarks</button>


{% endif %}
```

My javascript:

```js
function reportss (municipal,province,barangay,payout_type , list  ) {
  console.log(municipal + province + barangay)

  console.log(list) //this is list to pass

  if (barangay==""){

    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'reports' %}",
      data: {
          'id': municipal,
          'prov':province,
          'barangay':barangay,
          'mun': municipal,
          'p_type': payout_type
      },
      success: function(response){
        document.getElementById("total_paidss").innerHTML = response.paid;
        document.getElementById("total_unpaidss").innerHTML = response.unpaid;
        document.getElementById("total_amounts").innerHTML = response.amount;
        document.getElementById("total_counts").innerHTML = response.counts;
        document.getElementById("paid_total_amount").innerHTML = response.paid_total_amount;
        document.getElementById("unpaid_total_amount").innerHTML = response.unpaid_total_amount;
        $("#rports").modal('show');
        $("#rports").val(null).trigger("change");
      }
  });
  }
  else {

    console.log("else")
    console.log(municipal)
    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'reports' %}",
      data: {
          'id': municipal,
          'prov':province,
          'barangay':barangay,
          'mun': municipal,
          'p_type': payout_type
      },
      success: function(response){
        document.getElementById("total_paidss").innerHTML = response.paid;
        document.getElementById("total_unpaidss").innerHTML = response.unpaid;
        document.getElementById("total_amounts").innerHTML = response.amount;
        document.getElementById("total_counts").innerHTML = response.counts;
        document.getElementById("paid_total_amount").innerHTML = response.paid_total_amount;
        document.getElementById("unpaid_total_amount").innerHTML = response.unpaid_total_amount;
        $("#rports").modal('show');
        $("#rports").val(null).trigger("change");
      }
  });

  }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you to print value of `getlist` to console. Python uses single quote char (`'`) in string representations of array so there could be a conflict, cause you're using it as well. But I'm not sure that you need quotes around `{{list}}` at all.

Comment: Can you provide more information? This is very unclear.

Comment: @Shayan [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1mtW.png) I have this

Comment: @Shayan I don't know why it keeps telling me missing ( and now I tried dummy list but it error appears always [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRZFV.png)  it is possible that my error is in this line? `getlist = request.POST.getlist('batch[]')`

Comment: @HannahMae, `request.POST.getlist()` returns list. You pass list to  `format()` function which will call `repr()` to get string representation. In your template you pass all arguments as strings, but here you got syntax error because string representation of list contains single quotes and you're using single quotes in your js too.

Comment: @Olvin Roght thanks for your response but how I'm gonna change it? this the console looks like [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkPDb.png)

Comment: @HannahMae, I still not clearly understand what're you trying to achieve. Pass list as argument?

Comment: Also, may be the {{list|safe}} filter helps

Comment: @Olvin Roght Yes I want to pass after onclick to this function [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbTUw.png) in this example I just want to test the output through console , the output must be list it depends

Comment: This error is not specifically about your "list". It is coincidence that you have a variable named "list". it is most likely caused by some typos. maybe you have one more ")" after a function. It will be better if you show the whole html file together with your javascript code.

Comment: @ha-neul thanks for your response, I been adding my whole file both views and html can you check it out where's the problem?

Comment: to your javascript file, at the end, add ```}```.

Comment: @ha-neul I've update my javascript but the result is the same, I think the problem is not in the javascript, and I don't know why I'm getting this error

Comment: @HannahMae, I've already answered twice, the problem is that you're trying to pass list as string and it creates syntax error.

Comment: @Olvin Roght thanks for helping me, but what should I gonna do?